# Error while running invoke.js in ibm blockchain platform using vscode?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I have been using IBM blockchain platform using vs code. Everything is working fine, I can connect to fabric local, but the main problem is while I run invoke.js

```
Connected to Fabric gateway.
2019-10-24T03:40:03.358Z - error: [Channel.js]: Channel:mychannel received discovery error:access denied
2019-10-24T03:40:03.358Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
2019-10-24T03:40:03.358Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
Error processing transaction. Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
Error: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 1 Peers. Last error was Error: Channel:mychannel Discovery error:access denied
    at Network._initializeInternalChannel (/home/cybrosys/VSCodeLocalNetwork/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:112:12)
Disconnect from Fabric gateway.
done
```